# Centralizer of a cyclic subgroup within the group algebra $\mathbb{C} S_N$ of the symmetric group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, centralisers

Let us take the group algebra $\mathbb{C} S_N$ and the subgroup $H=Z_N$ generated by the element
$\sigma=(123\dots N)$, which is a cyclic shift. What is the structure of the centralizer of $H$ within $\mathbb{C} S_N$? If we
are looking at the Lie algebra $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C} S_N)$ obtained from the usual 
commutator of two elements, then what is the centralizer of the commutative sub-algebra $\mathbb{C} H$?

My motivation for this comes from physics, where the special ordering $1,2,3,\dots N$ has a
concrete physical meaning, for example actual atoms are placed next to each other. In this case those
group algebra elements that commute with $\sigma$ are called ``translationally invariant''
permutation operators, under periodic boundary conditions.

Ultimately I would like to know what is the maximal number of mutually commuting operators within
$\mathbb{C} S_N$ that commute with $\mathbb{C} H$, and how to find explicit bases for them. I wanted to approach this through the structure of
the Lie algebra $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C} S_N)$, decomposition into simple Lie algebras, etc. I understand
that the irreducible subspaces in $\mathbb{C} S_N$ correspond to the Young symmetrizers. But it is not
so clear what to do from here, how to add the action of the concrete element $\sigma$ into this.

Comment: Aren't the Lie centraliser and the group/algebra centraliser the same, since the first demands that $h X - X h = 0$ and the latter that $h X = X h$ for all $h \in H$?

Comment: Yes. I just mentioned the Lie algebras, because it is easier for me to think about them, I am more used to that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Mark Wildon and the OP for pointing out that my answer was incorrect- I was considering the centralizer of $\sigma$ in the wrong algebra.
    However, it does seem to me that the structure of $A = C_{\mathbb{C}S_{N}}(\sigma)$ depends on the prime factorization of $N.$

In general it is well-known that if $\lambda$ is a partition of $N$ and $\chi_{\lambda}$ is the associated complex irreducible character of $S_{N}$, then $\chi_{\lambda}(\sigma) \in \{0,1,-1 \}$.

When $N= p$ is prime, this implies that ${\rm Res}^{S_{N}}_{\langle \sigma \rangle}(\chi_{\lambda})$ has the form $t\rho + \chi_{\lambda}(\sigma)1, $ where $t= \frac{\chi_{\lambda}(1) - \chi_{\lambda}(\sigma)}{p}$ is a non-negative integer and $\rho$ is the regular character of $\sigma$. But this is never the case for all $\chi_{\lambda}$ when $N$ is not prime.

Now $\mathbb{C}S_{N}$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{\lambda} M_{\chi_{\lambda}(1)}( \mathbb{C})$ as $\lambda$ runs through partitions of $N$. Now $\sigma$ acts as a matrix of trace $0$ or $\pm 1$ inside  $M_{\chi_{\lambda}(1)}( \mathbb{C}).$

In the former case, the fixed subalgebra of $\sigma$ on the matrix algebra $M_{\chi_{\lambda}(1)}( \mathbb{C})$ has dimension
$\frac{\chi_{\lambda}(1)^{2}}{p}.$

In the latter cases, we may compute the dimension of the fixed fixed subalgabra of $\sigma$  in the relevant matrix algebra.

If ${\rm Res}^{S_{N}}_{\langle \sigma \rangle }(\chi_{\lambda})= t_{\lambda} \rho  \pm 1,$ then the fixed subalgebra of $\sigma$ in the matrix algebra 
has dimension $(p-1)t_{\lambda}^{2} + (t_{\lambda} \pm 1)^{2}
= pt_{\lambda}^{2} \pm 2t_{\lambda} +1$.

This means that when $N = p$ is prime, the dimension of the centralizer algebra of $\sigma$ in $\mathbb{C}S_{N}$ is totally detrmined by the values of the $\chi_{\lambda}(1)$ and $\chi_{\lambda}(\sigma)$, but his is not the case when $N$ is not prime.

Comment: I'm confused: $\dim \mathbb{C}S_N = |S_N| = N!$ whereas the dimension of any full matrix algebra of $(N-1)! \times (N-1)!$ matrices is at least $(N-1)!^2$, which is more whenever $N \ge 4$.

Comment: I agree with Mark, this seems to be too large.

Comment: I can't follow the penultimate paragraph. For $\mathbb{C}S_3$, the fixed subalgebra of $\langle (1,2,3) \rangle$ (acting by conjugation) has linear basis $\mathrm{id}$, $(1,2,3)$, $(1,3,2)$ and $(1,2) + (2,3) + (3,1)$. So its dimension is $4$, not $(3-1)!+1 = 3$. The factors in each matrix algebra are $1$ and $1$-dimensional (for the trivial and sign representations) and a $2$-dimensional semisimple commutative subalgebra of $\mathrm{End}_\mathbb{C}(S^{(2,1)})$.

Comment: Yes, thanks,  I had realised that too. I'll try to write more carefully what it really should be.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\IC}{\mathbb{C}}$
Let $V_\lambda$ be the irreducible $S_N$-module (Specht module). The representations $\rho_\lambda: \IC S_N \to \operatorname{End}_\IC(V_\lambda)$ give us an isomorphism of algebras $\IC[S_N] \to \prod_{\lambda \vdash N} \operatorname{End}_\IC(V_\lambda)$.

Since we work with $\IC$, the endomorphisms of finite order are always diagonalisable. In particular we can decompose $V_\lambda = \bigoplus_{k=0}^{N-1} V_{\lambda,k}$ such that $\sigma$ acts as multiplication by $\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{N}k)$ on $V_{\lambda,k}$. The centraliser of $\sigma$ is therefore exactly equal to $\prod_{\lambda\vdash N, 0\leq k<N} \operatorname{End}_\IC(V_{\lambda,k})$.

This reduces the problem to finding the commutative subalgebras of $\IC^{d\times d}$ of maximal dimension for all dimensions $d$. If I'm not mistaken, the subalgebra of diagonal matrices is of maximal dimension among the commutative subalgebras of $\IC^{d\times d}$, i.e. the maximal dimension is just $d$ itself.

Therefore the maximal dimension of a commutative subalgebra inside the $C_{\IC S_N}(\sigma)$ is $\sum_{\lambda,k} \dim(V_{\lambda,k}) = \sum_\lambda \dim(V_\lambda)$. The dimensions $\dim(V_\lambda)$ can be calculated by the [hook length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula).

In principle this approach also tells you how to find a set of basis elements: Find an eigen-basis for $\sigma$ inside each $V_\lambda$. The diagonal matrices w.r.t. to this basis will give you a basis of a commutative subalgebra of maximal dimension.

Comment: The complete matrix algebra of $d \times d$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ ($\mathbb{C}^{d \times d}$ in the notation above) has (unital) commutative subalgebras of dimension about $d^2/4$: take the nilpotent block matrices with non-zero entries only in the top-right corner, and extend by the identity matrix. Your claim is correct for semisimple algebras. Maybe this is enough?

Comment: Well, this certainly complicated things. is that the maximum? In this case one would need to actually know the dimensions $\dim(V_{\lambda,k})$ to get the precise value. I'm sure this is doable given how much is known about the representations of the symmetric group, but off the top of my head, I don't know how to calculate $d_{\lambda,k}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But again I am confused. The endomorphism you are mentioning is conjugation with $\sigma$, right? But then I specifically need the eigenstates with $k=0$, and not all $k$.

Comment: And a small comment about what I want later: this is for physics, these will be some operators in Quantum Mechanics. So they have to be Hermitian. In this language I define Hermitian conjugate for the basis of the algebra simply as the inverse of the permutation. And then it is extended to the whole group algebra. So when I understand the matrix algebra decomposition, I will basically want the Cartan subalgebra of each block. Sorry I was not precise about this. I am not interested of other possibilities of abelian subalgebras.

Comment: Well if you want hermitian operators that commute with $\sigma$, then my answer stands, because all hermitian operators are diagonalisable and commuting operators are simultaneously diagonalisable so that the algebra of diagonal matrices is in fact the unique-up-to-conjugation maximal commutative sub-*-algebra of $\mathbb{C}^{d\times d}$.

Comment: Why do you say that you only need $k=0$, i.e. the fixed points of $\sigma$ ? The centraliser of $\sigma$ acts on non-fixed points too.

Comment: I think I had a different action in mind. When you take $\sigma$, then it generates an endomorphism for every $a\in \mathbb{C}S_N$ as $a\to \sigma a \sigma^{-1}$. We want those elements that commute with $\sigma$, so this linear operator should have eigenvalue 1. This is what I thought.

Also, from your answer I don't see how the $\sigma$ actually plays a role. In the end you find a total number of commuting Hermitian operators, which would be the same even when I don't require commutativity with $\sigma$.

Comment: On the other hand, perhaps I can understand this. Basically choosing $\sigma$ and its powers we ,,fix'' some of the Cartan generators in this Lie algebra to be some specific elements. But it does not alter the total maximal dimension of the Cartan subalgebra. (or sums of Cartan subalgebras)